# how to know to use div to build navigation menu

Tags: html, css

everyone I hope you are so fine I have a small question about CSS and HTML how can I use nav and div to create a navigation drop-down buttons? I have used them already and the output is so fine but I don't know if the way I used in writing the code for these elements the div and nav together is right? and do anyone have an idea about the specific role of div element? the code is placed below thanks a lot, friends

```
body { font-family: arial, sans-serif; }
.navclass { 
font-weight: bold;
            color: white;
            border: 2px dashed LightSkyBlue;
            border-width: 3px;
            text-align: center;
            width: 20em;
            background-color: SlateBlue;
            margin-top: 50px;
            margin-left: 450px; }
.navclass ul { display: none;
                 list-style: none;
                 margin: 0;
                 padding: 0;
}
.navclass:hover ul  { display: block;  }
.navclass ul li {  border-top: 2px solid LightSkyBlue;
                 background-color: white;
                 width: 20em;
                 color: black;
}
.navclass ul li:hover { background-color: LightSkyBlue;}
a { text-decoration: none; }
 .header{ background-color: LightSkyBlue; 
                  font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
                  font-size: 15pt;
                  text-align: center;
                  padding: 5px;
                  border: 3px dashed SlateBlue;
                  margin-top: 30px;
                  margin-bottom: 30px;
                  margin-right: 70px;
                  margin-left: 70px;
   }
```

CSS code is the above

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
        <head>
                      <meta charset="utf-8">
                      <title> first page </title>  
  
                      <link rel= "stylesheet"   type="text/css" href="myQ.css">        
        </head>
        <body>
                            
<div class="navclass"> 
<nav>
            Menu
       <ul>
             <li><a href="Lab03HTMLpage.html">first</a></li>
             <li><a href="Lab03CSSpage.html">second</a> </li>
             <li><a href="Lab03JSpage.html">third</a></li>
             <li><a href="Lab03resourcespage.html">fourth</a></li>
             <li><a href="lab03regpage.html">fifth</a></li>
     </ul>
 </nav> </div>
```

html code is the above

Comment: Re: _"[Does] anyone have an idea about the specific role of div element?"_ `<div>` is a standard non-semantic block-level element. The HTML5 semantic equivalent of `<div class="navclass">` is `<nav>`. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/nav

Comment: from your experience, do you recommend to use div inside nav ? or nav inside div? or because they are equivalent I can use one of them only ? thanks

Comment: You can use whatever nested markup you prefer. But for clarity, if you can use `<nav>` alone (ie. without `<div>`) then I would aim for this approach.